# Variable is both Global and Local

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name):
      global name
      self.name = name

  def greet(self, color):
      return "Hi, my name is {0}, and my favorite color is {1}".format(name, color)
```

When I try to run this I get an error that 'name' is both global and local, but if I take away the "global name" I get an error that says global 'name' name is not defined. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Don't you want `self.name`?

Comment: Please describe what you want to achieve. At present `name` lives in three different namespaces. Cool.

Comment: you'll have to use self.name and not name in the method `greet`

Answer (score 3):

You want:

```
def greet(self, color):
  return "Hi, my name is {0}, and my favorite color is {1}".format(self.name, color)
```

(note the `self.` before `name`).

without `global name`.

The error saying that `name` is not defined is because in `greet` the compiler does not know what `name` is. It was known in the constructor, and assigned to `self.name`, and that's how you should refer to it.

The `global` keyword is not related to your problem, you should avoid it in this case (consider reading [its documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#global) though).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the global statement.  You almost certainly don't want that, because **different "people" (instances) should have different names**.  They shouldn't all share the same global name, [unless you're modelling something really strange here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lIpev8JXJHQ).

So, you just want to make `name` to be an attribute of the class.  Then you will also need to *access it as an attribute* of the class in your `greet` method, ergo:

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name):
      self.name = name

  def greet(self, color):
      return "Hi, my name is {0}, and my favorite color is {1}".format(
          self.name, color
      )
```

You might also consider making `color` an attribute, and taking it out of the argspec for greet.